# Datetimepicker binding in knockout.js not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, datetimepicker

I have a view with a datetimepicker. I am not able to bind it in Knockout. Since the datetime picker end of the day has a textbox, I bind it the same way as other textboxes(which works fine) and assume it to contain the datetime value in text format but it does not get binded.

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimatedTime" data-bind="value: estimatedTime">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="estimatedAmt" data-bind="value: estimatedAmount">
```

This is my script which does not work for datetimepicker(estimatedTime) but works for a normal textbox(EstimatedAmount).

```
var Model = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.estimatedTime= ko.observable(initialData.estimatedTime);
        self.estimatedAmount= ko.observable(initialData.EstimatedAmount);

self.update = function () {

            });                    
      }

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

Why is there a difference and what is the easiest way to fix it?

Comment: type="datetime" or type="datetime-local"?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to incorporate another DOM-manipulating entity into Knockout. See this [datetimepicker fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/sd2gmhop/10/) for an example.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            defaultDate: valueAccessor()()
        };

        if (allBindingsAccessor() !== undefined) {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions !== undefined) {
                options.format = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format : options.format;
            }
        }

        $(element).datetimepicker(options);
        var picker = $(element).data('datetimepicker');

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });

        var defaultVal = $(element).val();
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value(moment(defaultVal, options.format));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (widget.date) {
                widget.setValue();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Great work. But do you mind explaining it to me as to what the code does. I'm failing to figure out how I can implement this code piece into my code.

Comment: This wasn't my work, I was just pointing to an example and had to copy code in so SO would let me link to a fiddle. In short, the binding handler does all the DOM-manipulation associated with the widget. Setup code goes in `init` and when-things-change code goes in `update`. The update here copies the variable value into the widget. The init sets up the widget to send its changes to the variable. Two-way binding.

Comment: If you need a binding handler for a widget you want to use, there is a good chance you can find one already written by googling `datepicker knockout binding handler` (substituting whatever your desired widget is for `datepicker`)